# Не могу запустить Node.js приложение на apache (centos)

Tags: node.js, apache, centos

Пытаюсь запустить node js приложение согласно этому гайду: https://habr.com/ru/post/558178/

Полностью застрял на моменте, когда всё установлено, приложение запущено через pm2 ,
но сервер отказывается выводить его через запрос к сайту.

При попытке ввести url сайта возникает ошибка:
`Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

При этом, если я создаю в каталоге файл index.html - я получаю к нему доступ, если остается только index.js - forbidden

В httpd.conf пытался дописывать index.js в `DirectoryIndex` , но безуспешно

В вышеупомянутом гайде упоминается проксирование, но в cent os нет команды `a2enmod proxy_http` , а аналога этой операции я не знаю и пока не смог найти.
Как заметно из описания, о centos и работе apache я знаю очень мало, столкнулся с этим довольно случайно.
Может кто-то знает, как решить проблему или хотя бы куда копать?

Comment: я правильно понял, что Вы застряли на моменте из статьи "Шаг 6. Проксирование Node.js-приложения через Apache2 Proxy"?

Comment: Да, но дело вероятно не в этом.
В убунте всё заработало даже без проксирования

Comment: Так, судя по ошибкам, у Вас проблемы с правами. chmod 777? или selinux не отключен? Впротчем, как я понял, Вы сентось бросили и перешли на убунту?